# Including the missing dates in the date column of pandas dataframe for a specific timespan

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a time series dataframe whose headers are "Date" & "Value"

Sample Dataframe:

```
    Date              Value
    2019-10-01      46486868.0
    2019-11-01      36092742.0
    2019-12-01      32839185.0
```

Unfortunately, the Date column has some missing months. For example, the dataset is supposed to be a monthly dataset for the years 2001-2010 but it is missing a few random months in each year.

Since I am making a time series model, I cant have missing dates so I have been trying to figure out a way to include the same.

I tried creating a pandas object as follows:

```
df_date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2001', end='11/1/2010', freq='MS')    
type(df_date)
```

*pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex*

But this is not getting merged with pandas dataframe. It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> was passed
```

The task at hand is to have all dates for each month in the time span by either matching it with another dataframe with all dates and `ffil` the values that are missing or somehow including the missing values in the existing dataframe.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: `Date` is a column or the index of your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Date` as index and reindex it with `df_date`:

```
df_date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='11/1/2020', freq='MS')
df = df.set_index('Date').reindex(df_date)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 Value
2019-01-01         NaN
2019-02-01         NaN
2019-03-01         NaN
2019-04-01         NaN
2019-05-01         NaN
2019-06-01         NaN
2019-07-01         NaN
2019-08-01         NaN
2019-09-01         NaN
2019-10-01  46486868.0
2019-11-01  36092742.0
2019-12-01  32839185.0
2020-01-01         NaN
2020-02-01         NaN
2020-03-01         NaN
2020-04-01         NaN
2020-05-01         NaN
2020-06-01         NaN
2020-07-01         NaN
2020-08-01         NaN
2020-09-01         NaN
2020-10-01         NaN
2020-11-01         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

`pd.date_range` returns an index object. You can create a dateframe with it like this:

```
df_date = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='1/1/2020', freq='MS')    })
```

and then you can merge

```
df_date.merge(df, on='Date', how='left')
```

Output:

```
         Date       Value
0  2019-01-01         NaN
1  2019-02-01         NaN
2  2019-03-01         NaN
3  2019-04-01         NaN
4  2019-05-01         NaN
5  2019-06-01         NaN
6  2019-07-01         NaN
7  2019-08-01         NaN
8  2019-09-01         NaN
9  2019-10-01  46486868.0
10 2019-11-01  36092742.0
11 2019-12-01  32839185.0
12 2020-01-01         NaN
```